# On button click, query string missing last key-value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, query-string, onload

## Objective

- A user will make a set of choices about what gifts they want to buy by clicking a series of buttons on `panel.html`, the data from those three choices **`pickOne`**, **`pickTwo`** and **`pickThree`** are saved in a query string and is passed to `gifts.html`
- On `document.ready` or `window.onload`, the values from the query
  string are concatenated and passed to an isotope.js filter, which sorts
  the gifts on the page based on the query

## Problem

- When clicking the next button on the final and third panel, the value of the third pick is not being added to the query string and it is appearing empty `pickThree=""`
- If I paste the url to go directly to that URL with the querystring,
  the page doesn't appear to filter results on `document.ready` or
  `window.onload`

### scripts.js

```
// Pass choices to query string
var pickOne = null;
var pickTwo = null;
var pickThree = null;

$(".btn--next").on("click", function(){

    // Progress bar circles
    var circleOneSelected = $(".circle--one").hasClass("is-selected");
    var circleTwoSelected = $(".circle--two").hasClass("is-selected");
    var circleThreeSelected = $(".circle--three").hasClass("is-selected");

    // Panel One options
    var giftsforHimSelected = $(".btn--option-him").hasClass("is-selected");
    var giftsforHerSelected = $(".btn--option-her").hasClass("is-selected");
    var giftsforKidsSelected = $(".btn--option-kids").hasClass("is-selected");
    var giftsforAnyoneSelected = $(".btn--option-anyone").hasClass("is-selected");

    // Panel Two options
    var typeHimJewelry = $(".btn--option-him-jewelry").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeHimScarves = $(".btn--option-him-scarves").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeHimFishing = $(".btn--option-him-fishing").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeHimCologne = $(".btn--option-him-cologne").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeHimShirts = $(".btn--option-him-shirts").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeHimSports = $(".btn--option-him-sports").hasClass("is-selected");

    var typeHerCashmere = $(".btn--option-her-cashmere").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeHerPerfume = $(".btn--option-her-perfume").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeHerScarves = $(".btn--option-her-scarves").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeHerSweaters = $(".btn--option-her-sweaters").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeHerBeauty = $(".btn--option-her-beauty").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeHerCandles = $(".btn--option-her-candles").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeHerNecklaces = $(".btn--option-her-necklaces").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeHerJewelry = $(".btn--option-her-jewelry").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeHerWatches = $(".btn--option-her-watches").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeHerBags = $(".btn--option-her-bags").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeHerShoes = $(".btn--option-her-shoes").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeHerOther = $(".btn--option-her-other").hasClass("is-selected");

    var typeAnyoneCookbooks = $(".btn--option-anyone-cookbooks").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeAnyoneSpirits = $(".btn--option-anyone-spirits").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeAnyoneSuitcases = $(".btn--option-anyone-suitcases").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeAnyoneFood = $(".btn--option-anyone-food").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeAnyoneGardening = $(".btn--option-anyone-gardening").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeAnyoneGadgets = $(".btn--option-anyone-gadgets").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeAnyoneStLouis = $(".btn--option-anyone-stlouis").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeAnyoneGiveBack = $(".btn--option-anyone-giveback").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeAnyoneFitness = $(".btn--option-anyone-fitness").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeAnyoneSubscriptions = $(".btn--option-anyone-subscriptions").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeAnyoneOrnaments = $(".btn--option-anyone-ornaments").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeAnyonePets = $(".btn--option-anyone-pets").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeAnyonePersonalized = $(".btn--option-anyone-other").hasClass("is-selected");
    var typeAnyoneOther = $(".btn--option-anyone-other").hasClass("is-selected");

    // Panel Three options
    var under25 = $(".btn--option-25").hasClass("is-selected");
    var under50 = $(".btn--option-50").hasClass("is-selected");
    var under75 = $(".btn--option-75").hasClass("is-selected");
    var under100 = $(".btn--option-100").hasClass("is-selected");
    var under250 = $(".btn--option-u250").hasClass("is-selected");
    var over250 = $(".btn--option-o250").hasClass("is-selected");

    var btnLikeSelected = $(".btn--like").hasClass("is-selected");
    var btnSpendSelected = $(".btn--spend").hasClass("is-selected");

    // // Pass choices to query string
    // var pickOne = "";
    // var pickTwo = "";
    // var pickThree = "";

    var data = {
        pickOne: pickOne,
        pickTwo: pickTwo,
        pickThree: pickThree
    }

    if (circleOneSelected) {

        if (giftsforHimSelected) {
            completeStepOne();
            showPanelHim();
            pickOne = ".GiftsForHim";
            console.log(pickOne);

        } else if (giftsforHerSelected) {
            completeStepOne();
            showPanelHer();
            pickOne = ".GiftsForHer";
            console.log(pickOne);

        } else if (giftsforKidsSelected) {
            completeStepsOneTwo();
            showPanelThree();
            pickOne = ".GiftsForKids";
            console.log(pickOne);

        } else if (giftsforAnyoneSelected) {
            completeStepOne();
            showPanelAnyone();
            pickOne = ".GiftsForAnyone";
            console.log(pickOne);
        }
    }

    if (circleTwoSelected && btnLikeSelected) {
        completeStepTwo();
        showPanelThree();

        // Gifts he might like
        if (typeHimJewelry) {
            pickTwo = ".Jewelry";
        } else if (typeHimScarves) {
            pickTwo = ".Scarves";
        } else if (typeHimFishing) {
            pickTwo = ".Fishing";
        } else if (typeHimCologne) {
            pickTwo = ".Cologne";
        } else if (typeHimShirts) {
            pickTwo = ".Shirts";
        } else if (typeHimSports) {
            pickTwo = ".Sports";

        // Gifts she might like
    } else if (typeHerCashmere) {
        pickTwo = ".Cashmere";
    } else if (typeHerPerfume) {
        pickTwo = ".Perfume";
    } else if (typeHerScarves) {
        pickTwo = ".Scarves";
    } else if (typeHerSweaters) {
        pickTwo = ".Sweaters";
    } else if (typeHerBeauty) {
        pickTwo = ".Beauty";
    } else if (typeHerCandles) {
        pickTwo = ".Candles";
    } else if (typeHerNecklaces) {
        pickTwo = ".Necklaces";
    } else if (typeHerJewelry) {
        pickTwo = ".SportsJewelry";
    } else if (typeHerWatches) {
        pickTwo = ".Watches";
    } else if (typeHerBags) {
        pickTwo = ".SuitcasesBags";
    } else if (typeHerShoes) {
        pickTwo = ".Shoes";
    } else if (typeHerOther) {
        pickTwo = ".Other";

        // Gifts they might like
    } else if (typeAnyoneCookbooks) {
        pickTwo = ".Cookbooks";
    } else if (typeAnyoneSpirits) {
        pickTwo = ".Spirits";
    } else if (typeAnyoneSuitcases) {
        pickTwo = ".Suitcases";
    } else if (typeAnyoneFood) {
        pickTwo = ".Food";
    } else if (typeAnyoneGardening) {
        pickTwo = ".Garden";
    } else if (typeAnyoneGadgets) {
        pickTwo = ".Gadgets";
    } else if (typeAnyoneStLouis) {
        pickTwo = ".StLouis";
    } else if (typeAnyoneGiveBack) {
        pickTwo = ".GiveBack";
    } else if (typeAnyoneFitness) {
        pickTwo = ".Fitness";
    } else if (typeAnyoneSubscriptions) {
        pickTwo = ".Subscription";
    } else if (typeAnyoneOrnaments) {
        pickTwo = ".Ornaments";
    } else if (typeAnyonePets) {
        pickTwo = ".Pets";
    } else if (typeAnyonePersonalized) {
        pickTwo = ".Personalized";
    } else if (typeAnyoneOther) {
        pickTwo = ".Other";
    }
}

if (circleThreeSelected && btnSpendSelected) {

    if (under25) {
        var pickThree = ".Under25";
    } else if (under50) {
        var pickThree = ".Under50";
    } else if (under75) {
        var pickThree = ".Under75";
    } else if (under100) {
        var pickThree = ".Under100";
    } else if (under250) {
        var pickThree = ".Under250";
    } else if (over250) {
        var pickThree = ".Over250";
    }

    var query = jQuery.param(data);
    window.open("http://staging.graphics.stltoday.com/apps/giftguide/gifts.html?"+query);
}
});
```

## gifts.html

This script should run if the final next button is clicked on `panel.html` or going directly to that URL

```
<script>
        $(function(){

            // if (window.location.href.indexOf("?" && "pickOne=." && "pickTwo=." && "pickThree=.") !== -1) {
            if (window.location.href.indexOf("?") !== -1) {

                console.log(window.location.href);

                function getParameterByName(name, url) {
                    if (!url) {
                      url = window.location.href;
                    }
                    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
                    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                        results = regex.exec(url);
                    if (!results) return null;
                    if (!results[2]) return '';
                    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
                }

                var paramOne = getParameterByName("pickOne");
                var paramTwo = getParameterByName("pickTwo");
                var paramThree = getParameterByName("pickThree");

                var filter = paramOne+paramTwo+paramThree
                console.log(filter);

                var $grid = $('.gifts').isotope({
                    itemSelector: '.gift',
                    layoutMode: 'masonry',
                    getSortData: {
                        name: '.gift__name',
                        price: '.gift__price parseInt',
                    },
                    sortAscending: {
                        name: true,
                        price: true
                    }
                });

                $grid.isotope({ filter: filter });

                // If your query returns zero results, then make another search
                var filter = $('.gifts').filter(function () {
                    return this.style.display == 'none'
                });

                if (filter.length === 0) {
                    console.log("There are no results");
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

### panel.html

```
    <!-- Panel Three -->
    <div class="panel panel--three is-hidden">

<!--     <div class="advertising advertising--horizontal">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/720x90">
    </div> -->

        <div class="panel__inner inner--spend">
            <div class="panel__info">
                <h2 class="panel__title">How much do you want to spend?</h2>
                <h3 class="panel__instructions pick--one">Pick one of the options below</h3>
                <!-- <h3 class="panel__instructions">Remember, it's the thought that counts</h3> -->
            </div>

            <div class="button__group">
                <button class="btn btn--option btn--option-25 btn--spend">Under $25 <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn--option btn--option-50 btn--spend">Under $50 <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn--option btn--option-75 btn--spend">Under $75 <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn--option btn--option-100 btn--spend">Under $100 <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn--option btn--option-u250 btn--spend">Under $250 <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn--option btn--option-o250 btn--spend">$250 and over <i class="fa fa-check is-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>

            <div class="button__group button__controls">
                <button class="btn btn--previous previous--three"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Previous</button>
                <a href="/gifts.html" class="link--three"><button class="btn btn--next next--three">Next <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></a>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- .panel__inner -->
    </div> <!-- .panel .panel--three -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating new pickThree instances using the var keyword, so the original pickThree instance that was added to data never gets set with a value. You need to remove the var keywords like so:

```
if (under25) {
    pickThree = ".Under25";
} else if (under50) {
    pickThree = ".Under50";
} else if (under75) {
    pickThree = ".Under75";
} else if (under100) {
    pickThree = ".Under100";
} else if (under250) {
    pickThree = ".Under250";
} else if (over250) {
    pickThree = ".Over250";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the `var` is not the solution as the query string still produces an empty value for the third pick

Comment: Removing the `var` gives me a query string that looks like `l?pickOne=.GiftsForHim&pickTwo=.Jewelry&pickThree=`